# How to return an image in an HTTP response with CherryPy

Tags: python, http, cherrypy, cairo

I have code which generates a Cairo `ImageSurface`, and I expose it like so:

```
def preview(...):
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    ...
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
    return surface.get_data()
preview.exposed = True
```

This doesn't work (browsers report that the image has errors).

I've tested that `surface.write_to_png('test.png')` works, but I'm not sure what to dump the data into to return it. I'm guessing some file-like object? According to [the pycairo documentation](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#class-imagesurface-surface), `get_data()` returns a buffer. I've also now tried:

```
tempf = os.tmpfile()
surface.write_to_png(tempf)
return tempf
```

Also, is it better to create and hold this image in memory (like I'm trying to do) or write it to disk as a temp file and serve it from there? I only need the image once, then it can be discarded.

Comment: How about `write_to_png_stream`? http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1Surface.html#b3eca5bc13abe27f470fdf08134269bb

Comment: pycairo doesn't seem to expose that method... http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/surfaces.html#class-imagesurface-surface

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add these imports:

```
from cherrypy.lib import file_generator
import StringIO
```

and then go like this:

```
def index(self):
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"

    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    surface.write_to_png(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)

    return file_generator(buffer)
```

Additionaly, if you're serving standalone file (i.e. it's not a part of a web page) and you don't want it to be rendered into browser but rather treated as a file to save on a disk then you need one more header:

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.png"'
```

> Also, is it better to create and hold
>   this image in memory (like I'm trying
>   to do) or write it to disk as a temp
>   file and serve it from there? I only
>   need the image once, then it can be
>   discarded.

If the only thing you want to do is to serve this file to a browser there is no reason to create it on a disk on the server. Quite the contrary - remember that accessing hard disk brings performance penalty.

Comment: Works great! For the bounty, could you explain to me why?

Comment: Great answer, zifot - I think the key is using "write_to_png" which converts the raw data to PNG format.  Just using surface.get_data() won't work because it's not stored internally as PNG data (it's ARGB_32).

Comment: @Marc Novakowski - Thanks. You're right, ImageSurface holds data in memory in one of the formats described here: http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-image-surface.html#cairo-format-t. Format of output file is a different story.

Comment: @colinmarc - AFAIK if you question has a bounty then both awarding it and accepting the answer (which are now separate actions) are possible no sooner than two days after creating a bounty.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I was really stuck for a while there. =)

Answer (score 2):

You're failing because of not understand the working of `surface.get_data()`.
You are trying to return mime-type `image/png` but `surface.get_data()` returns
plain bitmap image (is not a Windows Bitmap file .BMP with header) which 
is plain image dump from "virtual screen" (surface)

Like this:

```
0000010000
0000101000
0001000100
0010000010
0001000100
0000101000
0000010000
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `return str(surface.get_data())`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 'file in memory' approach

```
return StringIO.StringIO(surface.get_data())
```