# Serve matplotlib figures with Cherrypy

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, cherrypy

How do I get Cherrypy to display a figure generated by `matplotlib`?

This is my code so far, but it's generating a 404:

```
import cherrypy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO


class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
            return """
<html>
<body>
<p>Yo!</p>
            <form method="get" action="generate">
              <p>Testerr</p>
              Start: <input type="text" value="010115" name="start" />
              <button type="submit">Go!</button>
            </form>
<body>
<html>
"""
    @cherrypy.expose
    def generate(self, start):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot([1,2,3,4])

        figdata=BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(figdata, format='png')

        imdata = figdata.getvalue()
        return imdata


cherrypy.config.update({
    'environment': 'production',
    'log.screen': False,
    'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port': 18892,
})
cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: What route are you navigating to (for example `127.0.0.1:18892/some/route`) in order to get the 404?

Comment: It's going to `.../generate?start=010115`

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064374/how-to-return-an-image-in-an-http-response-with-cherrypy

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've just tried that but it doesn't seem to be working - very annoying.

Comment: I've tested your code, and (except for a typo I guess "plt.plt()" -> "plt.plot()") it's working.